# local storage/sessionStorage not working in IE from local file system

Tags: javascript, html

This code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it fails when I run the same in Edge and IE. Why?

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Does anything works on IE? :D

Comment: @Adriani6, Okay i changed the question. Anyway sessionStorage/localStorage both are not working

Comment: I am not sure if IE considers `file:` as secure context. It doesn't support `window.isSecureContext` so it might be difficult to confirm.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, It works fine when we run this from fiddle or some other online editors, can u please try saving the same code in a file, and run it from your local system.

Comment: Are you running on your local machine? Ie. from a URL on your `C:/` drive? If so, that may be the issue due to security restrictions. Try running this on a webserver.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yeah am trying on my local machine, Okay got u, But is there is any way to store in local machines also?

Comment: No. Never work on your local file system as there are heightened security policies which will interfere with valid logic. Always run on a web server. You can easily install one on your machine. If you're using Windows then IIS can be installed in 2 minutes without downloading anything. You just need to enable it.

Comment: Internet Explorer has a couple of issues with local storage. First of all, it doesn't work at all in versions prior to 8 -- you don't specify the version you're running in your post.

Be sure to check out Mark Pilgrim's excellent HTML5 resource, which includes some IE-specific code for detecting the storage event:

[http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)